# how to detect the active (selected slide) in angular ui carousel ? but not angular-ui-bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is my html code , does there's any ways to detect the active slider either in html or in js code ?

please any answer to this question because i searched far and while on the internet but without any avail ...

```
                <carousel-item ng-class="active">

                    <div class="single-photo">

                        <figure><img ng-src="{{constants.IMG.cityGuide +'/'+ item.name}}" alt="{{res.city.search_name}}" /></figure>

                        <figcaption class="author-class">Photo by
                            <a href="#">john smith</a>                            </figcaption>
                    </div>
                </carousel-item>
                <carousel-prev>
                    <button class="slick-arrow" style="display: block;">
                        <span class="icon-arrow-1-left" ></span>

                    </button>
                </carousel-prev>

                <carousel-next>

                    <button class="slick-arrow" style="display: block;">
                        <span class="icon-arrow-1-right"></span>

                    </button>

                </carousel-next>

            </ui-carousel>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678252/get-active-slide-index-outside-angular-ui-bootstrap-carousel